# NullPointerException when saving Bitmap to SD card

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, bundle, android-bitmap

I'm trying to take a picture and save it into the SD, but at a certain point (after the photo has been taken) I get the NullPointerException. Here's the code:

```
    package com.social.bearv2;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Articolo extends Activity {
 private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE = 0;
 Intent i;
 private Button ib;
 private ImageView imview;

  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.article);
  ib = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);
  imview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imview);

   ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       File photoFile = null;
       try {
           photoFile = createImageFile();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           // Error occurred while creating the File
       }
       // Continue only if the File was successfully created
       if (photoFile != null) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
    startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE);
   }
   }
  });
 }
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       try {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Image Captured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");  
    imview.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
   } catch (NullPointerException ex) {

   }
   } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  }
 }

 private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "BeAR_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  imageFileName);
        return photo;
    }

}
```

Note that the line of code that gives me the exception is the "Bundle extras = data.getExtras();"

And this is the logcat:

```
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225): Process: com.social.bearv2, PID: 24225
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.social.bearv2/com.social.bearv2.Articolo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3385)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3428)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:145)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1254)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at com.social.bearv2.Articolo.onActivityResult(Articolo.java:61)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3381)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE will pass a small Bitmap image to onActivityResult - but only if you don't supply a file URI in EXTRA_OUTPUT.

You have specified where the image file should be stored, so Android assumes you will read the image from that file. This is why the Intent is null in onActivityResult.

Answer (score 0):

Here the `Intent data` is `null`...
The stacktrace says that `data` is `null`...

```
ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null // here}
```

and you are accessing a `null` instance at `Bundle extras = data.getExtras();`

You will not receive any data when you capture the image as you are passing output location. Your captured image will be saved at the location `photoFile`(The location you created)...

Comment: hmmmm... and how should I solve it?! I can't access photofile from onactivityresult :S

Comment: @LeonGuerrero hold the instance of `Uri` that is returned from `Uri.fromFile(photoFile)` as a global variable...

Comment: so you say something like:
static var = Uri.fromFile(photoFile) 
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            var);

?

Comment: @Leon Guerrero Yeah... but better dont use static... just make it an instance variable...

Comment: can't do that btw. If I put all of the code right before the onCreate method a lot of errors appear and it screws up every other method...

Comment: @GopalRao where are you?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your log:

```
03-21 11:41:32.140: E/AndroidRuntime(24225): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null}
```

It says data is null. And in your onActivityResult you try to access data:

```
 Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
```

Comment: I know that I'm trying to access a null value. That's what I wrote xD

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data != null)
{
     Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
 System.out.println("extras" + extras);
 if (extras != null)
 {
    bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
    //setting image resource
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     }
}
else
{
      Log.v("tag" , "data was null");
}
```